# How to specify default contents for a new .tex file in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I would like have `Emacs` copy, by default, the contents of some defined file in the buffer of any non-existent `.tex` file I visit.

I am using `AUCTeX` and I believe that would be feasible by editing the file or variable that is responsible for appending the lines `%%% Local Variables:`, etc. in new `.tex` files, but I would prefer a solution by way of altering the `.emacs` file, for convenient portability and customizability.

In trying to look into it, I did encounter such `Emacs` hooks as `find-file[-noselect]-hook`, but I am unsure of how to specify that a hook will only be run for empty (non-existent) `.tex` files, or which Lisp function copies a file's contents in the current buffer.

*Note*: Use of the `\input{...}` command is not a work-around for what I intend to use this scheme for. To give a small example, I am trying to have the default `.tex` "skeleton" look somewhat like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\input{$HOME/defaults} %$
\title{ enter title here }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% document body %

\bibliography{ specify bib file here }

\end{document}
```

---

**Update**

Thanks to Tom, I've found that I can get the above default contents (and in an actually better way, too) by using `Emacs` skeletons along with `auto-insert-mode`. Hence, I would put the following in my `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(define-skeleton latex-skeleton
  "Default LaTeX file initial contents."
  "Title: "
  "\\documentclass[11pt]{article}\n\n"
  "\\input{\$HOME/defaults} %\$\n"
  "\\title{ "str | " ENTER TITLE HERE " "}\n\n"
  "\\begin{document}\n"
  "\\maketitle\n\n"
  ""_"\n\n"
  "\\bibliography{" (skeleton-read "BIB-file: ") | " SPECIFY BIB FILE HERE " "}\n\n"
  "\\end{document}\n")

(require 'autoinsert)
(add-hook 'find-file-hooks 'auto-insert)
(setq auto-insert-query nil)
(setq auto-insert-alist 
      '(("\\.tex$" . latex-skeleton)))
```

However, this does not work for `.tex` files, nor does it work for `latex-mode` (specified by changing the last line above to `'((latex-mode . latex-skeleton)))`)!

If, instead, I use any other file extension or `Emacs` major mode it works fine. Therefore, I believe this to be caused by the `AUCTeX`-defined default actions on visiting a new `.tex` file, such as prompting the user to set the master file, appending lines like `%%% Local Variables:`, etc.

How could it be possible that I set `AUCTeX` to incorporate my customizations to its defaults? Or would there be some other work-around?

Comment: Your customization works for me: if I start with `emacs -Q -l /path/to/auctex`, and then evaluate your snippet, and open a new tex file the skeleton does run as expected.  So there must be something else in your `.emacs` that is causing it to not work.  If you can track it down by doing a binary search of your `.emacs` then we can find a work around.

Comment: @IvanAndrus's suggestion also works for me. I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know about [auto insert mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode)?

Comment: Thanks! `auto-insert-mode` seems to be just the thing, particularly if used in conjunction with skeletons. Unfortunately, however, it seems that the default actions defined by `AucTeX` (e.g. prompting for a master file, and appending `%%% Local Variables: `, and so forth) suppress the _auto-insert_ actions I define in my `.emacs` file... (I've updated my question as well.)